# Significance of text inside square brackets

Tags: c#, crm, square-bracket

1. Hello, can you please explain me what is the significance of  `[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("activityid")]`  in the following code?

   ```
   [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("activityid")]
   public Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference ActivityId
   {
       get
       {
           return this.GetAttributeValue<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.EntityReference>("activityid");
       }
       set
       {
           this.OnPropertyChanging("ActivityId");
           this.SetAttributeValue("activityid", value);
           this.OnPropertyChanged("ActivityId");
       }
   }
   ```

   I searched for this thing and I got many posts which gave me answer as the ones in square brackets are **Attributes** in C#. But, then attributes are related with methods. Over here, `ActivityId` doesn't seem to be a method. So, how can `[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("activityid")]` act as an attribute?
2. Is it related to `C#` or it has got something to do with `CRM`?

Comment: @DavinTryon, I thought people will put comment saying it is possible duplicate of other posts. But, please read my Q properly. It says "I searched for this thing and I got many posts which gave me answer as the ones in square brackets are Attributes in C#. But, then attributes are related with methods. Over here, ActivityId doesn't seem to be a method. So, how can [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.AttributeLogicalNameAttribute("activityid")] act as an attribute?"

Comment: Attributes in C# can be applied to any attribute target (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Vikram Attributes are not limited to methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw5zxet9.aspx

Comment: @DavinTryon and Adam Houldsworth, Thanks for the explanation and the links. But, then what will be the use of attribute when it is used with field?

Comment: @Vikram Attributes are only used via reflection or sometimes via the compiler. The intended style of use is usually the same regardless of where it is applied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The confusion comes from your statement about attributes only being valid on methods. Attributes can be valid on items specified in the `AttributeTargets` enum:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attributetargets.aspx

This then puts you back to the answer being "they are attributes". That attribute has simply been applied to a property.

Comment: You are correct! I got it. But, then why a property would have an attribute? I mean, what is the use of it? Is it used with for 'set' inside that property?